# About Form Validation

Tags: validation, flutter

Where I am going wrong? Validation is not working. It is printing false on validation.Whereas text form field printing okay whereas validation is printing false.

```
Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(validator: (val) {
          if (val.length == 6) {
            print('okay');
          } else {
            print('error');
          }
        }),
        TextFormField(


            validator: (val) => val.length == 6 ? 'Okay' : 'dsfj'),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('test'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                print('true');
              } else {
                print('false');
              }
            })
      ]),
    ),
```

Comment: What not working? It not printing "okay"?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: see [FormFieldValidator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldValidator.html)  - it reads: *"Signature for validating a form field.

**Returns an error string to display if the input is invalid, or null otherwise**.

Used by FormField.validator."*

Comment: Basically I want to navigate to a new screen as my form validate. So how to do this

Comment: did you see my comment above? why dont you read the official documentation? if it is still unclear read some official tutorials like: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation#2-add-a-textformfield-with-validation-logic

Comment: got it But what if i want to go to a specific page only if the user enter correct data

Comment: Basically i am returning string in either conditions that's why my form validation is  not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I am returning string in validator even if condition validates.Hence `(_formKey.currentState.validate())` is returning false in both cases even text form fields validate or not.
So, try to return null if your condition fulfill to avoid such problems.

```
TextFormField(validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Password is too short' : null),
```

Like this.
Thanks

Comment: OK. You can mark your own answer  as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: Kindly can you give vote to my answer? If so please give vote to my answer.